# D3 Javascript - Probable issue with nested function -- generates console error

Tags: javascript, json, function, d3.js

Hello again Stackoverflow.   As is usually the case, once you fix the initial problem you gain another.   Yesterday I posted a question regarding
implementing a D3 Visualization.  My question was answered lickety-split by Sparta93 (maybe you can help on this one too).

As I pointed out I am actually embedding the D3 Viz inside a packaged application, Oracle Big Data Discovery (BDD).  BDD uses a Visualization
renderer to display the chart.   This requires the JS block to be inside a Chart function (the entire body of code is in a linked JS Fiddle below for ease of reading and review):

```
renderChart: function(queryResults) {
```

When I run the code it generates an error that
Stratify is not a function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: d3.stratify is not a function
at S.renderChart (script:44)
at S.executeQueryCallback (eval at globalEval (barebone.jsp:4), <anonymous>:1:3460)
at S.handleResize (eval at globalEval (barebone.jsp:4), <anonymous>:1:3751)
at constructor.resizeListener (eval at globalEval (barebone.jsp:4), <anonymous>:1:17193)
at Object.run (eval at globalEval (barebone.jsp:4), <anonymous>:1:16634)
at i (barebone.jsp:32)
```

If I reorder the code and place Cluster first I get a similar error.

I suspect the issue is related to the fact that these two functions being inside "renderChart: function(queryResults)".    I am DBA, Big Data and BI guy so my
JS skills are quite modest.  I likely barely hacked the code together enough to get it to work.    I have much simplier viz working in BDD that does
not error out.  It does not however have any sub-functions

Here is a Fiddle where the code works as expected (thanks to Sparta93). Chart working in "normal" context:  https://jsfiddle.net/hb4oLy2x/

Here is a Fiddle just for simplicity of posting all the code.  It will not run because it depends on the server-side BDD Visualization Renderer.   I placed some comments around the elements that I believe are the issue.  Chart not working in BDD context (this is the code with the issue):  https://jsfiddle.net/sx7oaput/

Here is a Fiddle where I removed the URI for d3 v4.  Interestingly it creates a similar error in the Console.  Chart code that simulates error (maybe just a coincidence):  https://jsfiddle.net/u48o39k2/

Here is a another Fiddle for simplicity of sharing the code.  This does render the Bar Chart and HTML table successfully in BDD.  Chart that does work in BDD context:  https://jsfiddle.net/j7r9f743/

Guidance, advice, and/or help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried looking at other courses of action because I knew that some visualizations did in fact work.  I found this code on line and when I extracted the individual pieces and tested replacements in the working code, I got it to work.

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
.separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth; });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xItvw

Many thanks to "CAPTAIN ANONYMOUS" the author of the Code Pen (lol).